# TARGET_SONAME_FILE points to enclosing directory rather than file-- but only on some platforms

Tags: cmake

We have a project with a CMake file. It builds some open-source libraries our project needs, and copies shared object files for some other closed-source libraries out of known locations. This currently works on Windows.

I have a branch where I am trying to add support for a particular shared library on Mac. I am seeing a weird CMake problem where the TARGET_SONAME_FILE property for the shared library target mysteriously drops the filename and sets itself to the directory only. The build, following the incorrect TARGET_SONAME_FILE, then turns out wrong.

If you want to test this yourself, check out [this repository](https://github.com/mcclure/lovr/tree/mac-spatializer-test-2), branch mac-spatializer-test-2, commit `189bfe8`, `git submodule update --init`, download [Steam Audio aka Phonon](https://valvesoftware.github.io/steam-audio/downloads.html), and run (paths adjusted for your own system)

```
mkdir build
(cd build && cmake -DLOVR_ENABLE_PHYSICS=NO -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DLOVR_USE_STEAM_AUDIO=1 -DLOVR_STEAM_AUDIO_PATH=/Users/mcc/Downloads/spatializers/steamaudio_api ..)
(cd build && cmake --build .)
```

...but that's a little complicated to build so I'll just describe the problem.

Early in our CMake file, if LOVR_USE_STEAM_AUDIO and APPLE are both set, we run:

```
add_library(Phonon SHARED IMPORTED)
message("Phonon IMPORTED_LOCATION: ${LOVR_STEAM_AUDIO_PATH}/lib/OSX/libphonon.dylib")
set_target_properties(Phonon PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${LOVR_STEAM_AUDIO_PATH}/lib/OSX/libphonon.dylib")
set(LOVR_PHONON Phonon)
```

Which is supposed to create a target and store an IMPORTED_LOCATION for it. Then later in the file, we run:

```
function(move_lib)
  if(TARGET ${ARGV0})
    add_custom_command(TARGET lovr POST_BUILD
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "TARGET ${ARGV0} COPY $<TARGET_SONAME_FILE:${ARGV0}>"
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
      $<TARGET_SONAME_FILE:${ARGV0}>
      ${EXE_DIR}/$<TARGET_SONAME_FILE_NAME:${ARGV0}>
    )
  endif()
endfunction()
move_lib(${LOVR_PHONON})
```

This is supposed to extract the previously set IMPORTED_LOCATION, and use that path to copy the file into a designated spot.

When we execute the CMake file, this prints out:

```
Phonon IMPORTED_LOCATION: /Users/mcc/Downloads/spatializers/steamaudio_api/lib/OSX/libphonon.dylib
...
TARGET Phonon COPY /Users/mcc/Downloads/spatializers/steamaudio_api/lib/OSX/
```

Somehow, the `libphonon.dylib` has been dropped. It tries to copy the directory, which is wrong, and COPY refuses to do it anyway, so this is a noop. The program then fails to find libphonon.dylib at runtime.

Essentially identical CMakeLists code works properly on Windows, and the one Linux user we have hasn't reported any problems. As far as I know it's failing on Mac. We have several other targets where we are doing something similar and the copy-TARGET_SONAME_FILE technique is working. One difference between SteamAudio/Phonon and the targets that are working correctly is the those are `add_library`-- Phonon's target is just used as a container to store the SHARED IMPORTED path, because we don't directly dynamically lnk Phonon, with that library we load at runtime using `dlopen` or similar.

One thing that I have already tried, which did not help, is adding `add_dependencies(lovr ${LOVR_PHONON})`. I am running CMake 3.20.0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Definitely open an issue on https://gitlab.kitware.com

Comment: You might need to set the [IMPORTED_SONAME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_SONAME.html) property.

Comment: I'm a bit curious why you're copying libraries this way. On macOS and Linux, you should be able to use RPATH to resolve libraries at build time. For installing files, there's the `install` command. You can also set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:...>`

Comment: Thanks, I will test with IMPORTED_SONAME and then file a gitlab issue.

Comment: As for why we are copying libraries this way-- so first off I do not decide the basic approach here. I am a contributor to the library, not the maintainer. I believe the maintainer's logic is that the current approach of copying all files into bin/ makes the process for building a distributable .app (where a copy really is necessary) more similar to the process for running a build in place while debugging. (We used to do it the other way.)

Comment: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22119